# Avoid displaying Microsoft version when running cmd.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, version

If I have a batch file, and I wish to prevent it from closing (hence allowing the user the run commands with a modified path) one would typically end the batch file with `cmd.exe`.

However, this annoying message disrupts my batch-files output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Is there an alternative means of keeping the window open, or preventing this text from appearing when I run cmd.exe?

Comment: Try running `cmd /c` instead of `cmd`

Comment: Or `cmd /k`, whichever suits you better ;)

Comment: It didn't work, cmd exits the program

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are running the batch script by double clicking it or via a shortcut.

One option is to create a shortcut and modify the target from `c:\yourPath\yourScript.bat` to `cmd /k "c:\yourPath\yourScript"`

Another option is to end your script with `cmd /k`